# Java recursive backtracking problem

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

Having some trouble with this recursive backtracking problem:

"Write a method **partitionable** that accepts a list of integers as a parameter and uses recursive backtracking to discover whether the list can be partitioned into two sub-lists of equal sum. Your method should return true if the given list can be partitioned equally, and false if not."

For example, the list [1, 2, 3] can be partitioned into the sublists [1, 2] and [3], so it would produce a result of "true."

My solution seems correct, but returns false no matter what. I don't understand why.

```
public static boolean partitionable(List<Integer> list1) {
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        return partitionable(list1, list2);
    }

public static boolean partitionable(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    boolean finalAnswer = false;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        sum1 += list1.get(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
        sum2 += list2.get(i);
    }
    if (sum1 == sum2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size() - 1; i++) {
            int number = list1.remove(i);
            list2.add(number);
            finalAnswer = partitionable(list1, list2);
            list2.remove(list2.size() - 1);
            list1.add(i, number);
        }
    }
    return finalAnswer;
}
```

EDIT: I fixed the problem of removing the element from list1 twice.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `list1.remove(i)` twice.  That will probably mess up your algorithm, because you're removing two numbers, and saving only one of them to add to `list2`.

If it's still not working, I've also noticed that you're neglecting the last element of `list1` as a candidate to go over to `list2`.  I don't see an algorithmic reason for this to happen: you should try removing the `-1` from your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is of calling `list1.remove(i)` twice. This won't work.

You'r removing two numbers from `list1` and while saving it in `list2`, you are saving only 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive case (the `else` block) should check to see if `finalAnswer == true`, and return it immediately if that's the case. Otherwise, you'll skip over it onto cases where `false` is returned, and eventually return that at the bottom.

That won't solve the whole problem, since you're also removing an item from `list1` twice. Fixing both should get you the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for not answering your question directly, but my understanding of the question posed necessitates a different answer.

The original question asks this:
`Your method should return true if the given list can be partitioned equally`

And you later claim this:
`[1, 2, 3] can be partitioned into the sublists [1, 2] and [3], so it would produce a result of "true."`

This rings incorrect to me.  Would the proper solution (ignoring the recursive backtracking requirement for a moment) be to count the number of integer elements, `% 2` and return `NOT result`?

In other words:

```
List has three elements.  
Divide by 2, remainder 1.
Return 0, list is not equally dividable.

List has four elements.
Divide by 2, remainder 0.
Return 1, list is equally dividable.
```

Please let me know where I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: the sub-list are to have equal sums, not equal numbers of elements

Comment: @hello253, AH, that makes a lot of sense now.  Thank you.